# align image button and input box

Tags: html, image, input, alignment

Im trying to align  (reletive towards eachothers horizontal center)  my image button with an input box but cant get it working.. all the examples I have seen online make use of a single image rather then a rollover image setup...

```
<body background="Images/Main_Background.png"> 

<center>
<a href="#"
   onclick="this.href = ('file:///V:/' + document.getElementById('prog_site').value + '/Tekeningen/Tekenwerk De Mar/Definitief/' + document.getElementById('prog_site').value + '.pdf' )"
   target="upper">

    <img src="Images/Zoek.png" border="0" alt="Form" width="40" height="40"
         onmouseover="this.src='Images/Zoek_Rollover.png'"
         onmouseout="this.src='Images/Zoek.png'"><input type="text" name="prog_site" id="prog_site" value="" /></Center>
    </img>

</body>
```

Comment: A working JSFiddle would be very useful

Answer (score 1):

Try something like: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JbdUj/)

```
div.cont {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
}
.cont img, .cont input{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax errors:

- Missing closing tag for `a`
- `img` tag is self-closed tag

Also what's the problem? Image and input is aligned to each other.
Some tips I think may help you:

- Add `line-height:` css attribute for `center` tag to max height of it's elements. In this case `40px` - image's height.
  ...